# Ruby mongodb: Three newly created objects doesn't appear to exist during testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, testing, rspec

I'm using mongodb to store some data. Then I have a function that gets the object with the latest timestamp and one with the oldest. I haven't experienced any issues during development or production with this method but when I try to implement a test for it the test fails approx 20% of the times. I'm using rspec to test this method and I'm not using mongoid or mongomapper.  I create three objects with different timestamps but get a nil response since my dataset contains 0 objects. I have read a lot of articles about write_concern and that it might be the problem with "unsafe writes" but I have tried almost all the different combinations with these parameters (w, fsync, j, wtimeout) without any success. Does anyone have any idea how to solve this issue? Perhaps I have focused too much with the write_concern track and that the problems lies somewhere else.

This is the method that fetches the latest and oldest timestamp.

```
def first_and_last_timestamp(customer_id, system_id)
  last = collection(customer_id).
    find({sid:system_id}).
    sort(["t",Mongo::DESCENDING]).
    limit(1).next()

  first = collection(customer_id).
    find({sid:system_id}).
    sort(["t",Mongo::ASCENDING]).
    limit(1).next()

  { min: first["t"], max: last["t"] }
end
```

Im inserting data using this method where data is a json object.

```
def insert(customer_id, data)
  collection(customer_id).insert(data)
end
```

I have reverted back to use the default for setting up my connection

```
Mongo::MongoClient.new(mongo_host, mongo_port)
```

I'm using the gem `mongo (1.10.2)`. I'm not using any fancy setup for my mongo database. I've just installed mongo using brew on my mac and started it. The version of my mongo database is `v2.6.1`.

Comment: some code would help us to help you. Please edit your question and add all relevant code and information there.

Comment: Definitely need some code to see how you're inserting and querying. Also, what sort of MongoDB deployment do you have (server version and standalone, replica set, or sharded cluster)? Write concern is likely unrelated unless you've explicitly turned this off and are ignoring some obvious exceptions like duplicate keys. The [default write concern](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/drivers-write-concern/) in all supported drivers changed to "Acknowledged" back in Nov-2012.

Comment: Sorry for excluding code examples. I was frustrated after battling this problem all day yesterday so I started writing this question on my commute home and I didn't have my laptop with me. I have however added some code examples now. Let me know if you need me to add any additional information.